# How to get @ViewChild from pug

Tags: angular, pug

I am writing an Angular2 application using pug. I have two versions of the template, my HTML works but my Pug does not can someone see what I am missing...

```
// HTML
<div #main>
    <h1>Test Html</h1>
</div>

//PUG
.app( #main )
    h1 My Angular App

// Component
import { ElementRef, Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
declare var $:JQueryStatic;
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  // template: String(require('./app.component.html'))
  template: String(require('./app.component.pug'))
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit{
  @ViewChild('main') el:ElementRef;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    $(this.el.nativeElement).css('background-color', 'red');
  }
}
```

The error I get for pug is...

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.) (" #main\u003E\u003Ch1\u003EMy Angular App\u003C\u002Fh1\u003E\u003C\u002Fdiv\u003E";;return pug_html;}[ERROR ->]"): AppComponent@0:221
Invalid ICU message. Missing '}'. (" #main\u003E\u003Ch1\u003EMy Angular App\u003C\u002Fh1\u003E\u003C\u002Fdiv\u003E";;return pug_html;}[ERROR ->]"): AppComponent@0:221 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:(…) Error: Template parse errors:
Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.) (" #main\u003E\u003Ch1\u003EMy Angular App\u003C\u002Fh1\u003E\u003C\u002Fdiv\u003E";;return pug_html;}[ERROR ->]"): AppComponent@0:221
Invalid ICU message. Missing '}'. (" #main\u003E\u003Ch1\u003EMy Angular App\u003C\u002Fh1\u003E\u003C\u002Fdiv\u003E";;return pug_html;}[ERROR ->]"): AppComponent@0:221
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what pug is or how it works, but if it at runtime adds HTML to the DOM it won't work. Angular doesn't process HTML in the DOM, it only processes its templates. `[propName]="..."`, `(eventName)="..."`, `{{}}` or component and directive selectors are just ignored by Angular2 if they are anywhere else than statically added to the template.

Using `@ViewChild()` together with jQuery seems rather pointless.
`@ViewChild()` helps let Angular2 do the DOM access and avoid direct DOM access from your custom code. If you use jQuery the whole point of avoiding direct DOM access is mute.

You can just inject `ElementRef`

```
constructor(private el:ElementRef) { }
```

to get a reference to the host element of the current component and start with jQuery from there.

Comment: Pug is a precompiler for HTML that is why the HTML works but pug doesn't pug doesn't understand the `<div #main>` (or in the case of pug `div(#main)`). The constructor part doesn't answer the question. I have to access Jquery on the element because I am injecting a jquery library.

Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: When and where does it compile? On the server or on the client after it's loaded into the browser? You can access the element inside the template from the `ElementRef` you get in the constructor. `$(this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('div'))` or similar.

Comment: This is a problem with the way pug transpiles the #main not anything to do really with the ng2 side. Unless there is a way I can use ViewChild without the `#main` syntax. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Angular2 recognizes `#someName` only when it's added statically to the template of the component. When it's added to the DOM, Angular won't recognize it at all. If you add it to the components template it also wont't be added to the DOM. Angular2 process it's components template before adding the result to the DOM. Angular binding and similar stuff never hits the DOM.

Comment: For now I can use the constructor but I eventually need the other so I will have to get creative or find someone that knows how to properly escape in pug

Comment: If pub works client-side you won't be able to get a template variable added that Angular can recognize. As mentioned this works only in Angular2 component templates, not in the DOM.

Comment: Sure. But as I mentioned I don't know what pub is. If you can give some basic information where it is applied, I'm pretty sure I can give hints if it is possible to work around and if yes, then how.

Comment: Sorry, just saw the typo. `pub` is one of my most use command line tools and therefore hard for me to write `pug` instead of `pub` ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125206/discussion-between-jackie-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Answer (score 2):

Pug/Jade does not allow for this. You may, however, write regular html into your .pug file to get the behavior you are looking for. Your pug would look like this:

```
//PUG
<div #main class="app">
  h1 My Angular App
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `doctype html` at the top of the pug-file.